# Converting a H256/bytes32 into a generic AccountId for EVM precompiles

Tags: pallet, evm, account, precompile

## Overview

We are building out a precompile for `pallet-staking` and have run into the tricky challenge of converting `H256` types into generic `AccountId`s so that we can implement functions like `nominate` specifically.

However, it seems there's no straightforward way to convert the `H256` into this type. Though, perhaps someone on this forum knows a way around it.

### Motivation

When you `nominate` you select a `Vec` of targets which are Substrate accounts for the validators. The generic type in the runtime is below:

- `type AccountIdLookupOf<T> = <<T as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source;`

This type is quite general. We'd like to go from a Substrate account provided in the EVM (32 bytes account so `H256`) into this source. We have tried a variety of methods shown below, but none work so far.

### Attempt #1 - Use `AccountIdLookup::unlookup`

```
#[precompile::public("nominate(address[])")]
    fn nominate(handle: &mut impl PrecompileHandle, targets: Vec<H256>) -> EvmResult {
        handle.record_log_costs_manual(2, 32 * targets.len());
        let origin = Runtime::AddressMapping::into_account_id(handle.context().caller);
        let converted_targets = targets
            .into_iter()
            .map(|target| {
                AccountIdLookup::<MultiAddress<Runtime::AccountId, AccountIndex>, AccountIndex>::unlookup(MultiAddress::Address32(target.0))
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let call = pallet_staking::Call::<Runtime>::nominate { targets: converted_targets };

        // Dispatch call (if enough gas).
        RuntimeHelper::<Runtime>::try_dispatch(handle, Some(origin).into(), call)?;

        Ok(())
    }
```

This yields the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> precompiles/staking/src/lib.rs:200:67
    |
200 |         let call = pallet_staking::Call::<Runtime>::nominate { targets: converted_targets };
    |                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Vec<<... as StaticLookup>::Source>`, found `Vec<MultiAddress<MultiAddress<..., ...>, ...>>`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Vec<<<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source>`
               found struct `Vec<MultiAddress<MultiAddress<<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, u32>, u32>>`
help: a method is available that returns `<<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source`
   --> /Users/drew/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:225:2
    |
225 |     fn unlookup(t: Self::Target) -> Self::Source;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ consider calling `unlookup`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

### Attempt #2 - Use `Runtime::unlookup` generically

```
let mut converted_targets: Vec<<Runtime::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source> = vec![];
        for i in 0..targets.len() {
            let target = targets[i];
            let converted_target = <Runtime::Lookup as StaticLookup>::unlookup(target.0.into());
            converted_targets.push(converted_target);
        }
        let call = pallet_staking::Call::<Runtime>::nominate { targets: converted_targets };
```

Yields the following error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: From<[u8; 32]>` is not satisfied
   --> precompiles/staking/src/lib.rs:197:80
    |
197 |             let converted_target = <Runtime::Lookup as StaticLookup>::unlookup(target.0.into());
    |                                                                                         ^^^^ the trait `From<[u8; 32]>` is not implemented for `<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
    |
    = note: required for `[u8; 32]` to implement `Into<<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
191 |     fn nominate(handle: &mut impl PrecompileHandle, targets: Vec<H256>) -> EvmResult where <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: From<[u8; 32]> {
    |                                                                                      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

## Questions

1. Are there any traits that come to mind similar to converting addresses into generic types in the EVM but for Substrate addresses / `[u8; 32]`?

Comment: Where can I learn about you `#[precompile::public("nominate(address[])")]` macro? Looks very cool.

Comment: It's taken from moonbeam's precompile infrastructure @JoshOrndorff. Also my approach didn't work primarily because the `AccountId` type used in the mock runtime still doesn't implement `From<[u8; 32]>`.

Comment: What concrete address type are you trying to convert into?

Comment: `AccountId32` basically. We solved this by re-implementing `AccountId32` but with some extra trait implementations and public inner value.